# how to check if multiple list items has the class Name "valid"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, if-statement, passwords

I am working on a password validation process. when the password input in a Sign up page is clicked a list of requirement is shown 
[image]

And if the created password respect one of the requirements a "valid" className will be added to the li that will add additional styles to it.

[image]

what I want to do next is to check if all requirements are respected and if so hide the list.
I tried this code here but  with no luck.

```js
const checkPassword = () => {
    const pswrd = document.getElementById("pswrd");
    const lowerCase = document.getElementById("lower");
    const upperCase = document.getElementById("upper");
    const digit = document.getElementById("number");
    const specialChar = document.getElementById("special");
    const minLength = document.getElementById("length");

    // get all li items with valid className
    const liList = document.querySelectorAll(".liList");

    //javascript regular expression pattern
    const data = pswrd.value;
    const lower = new RegExp("(?=.*[a-z])");
    const upper = new RegExp("(?=.*[A-Z])");
    const number = new RegExp("(?=.*[0-9])");
    const special = new RegExp("(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])");
    const length = new RegExp("(?=.{8,})");

    //lowerCase validation

    if (lower.test(data)) {
      lowerCase.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      lowerCase.classList.remove("valid");
    }
    if (upper.test(data)) {
      upperCase.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      upperCase.classList.remove("valid");
    }
    if (number.test(data)) {
      digit.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      digit.classList.remove("valid");
    }
    if (special.test(data)) {
      specialChar.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      specialChar.classList.remove("valid");
    }
    if (length.test(data)) {
      minLength.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      minLength.classList.remove("valid");
    }
  
  //check if all li items have the "valid" className
    if (liList.classList.contains("valid") === true) {
      console.log("I am working");
      setShowValidation(false);
    } else {
      setShowValidation(true);
    }
  };
  
  return (
      <div
      className={showValidation ? "validation active" : "validation "}
            >
              <ul>
                <li className="liList" id="lower">
                  At least one lowercase character
                </li>
                <li className="liList" id="upper">
                  At least one uppercase character
                </li>
                <li className="liList" id="number">
                  At least one number
                </li>
                <li className="liList" id="special">
                  At least one special character
                </li>
                <li className="liList" id="length">
                  At least 8 characters
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed it :

```js
 const [showValidation, setShowValidation] = useState(false);
 
 const checkPassword = () => {
    const pswrd = document.getElementById("pswrd");
    const lowerCase = document.getElementById("lower");
    const upperCase = document.getElementById("upper");
    const digit = document.getElementById("number");
    const specialChar = document.getElementById("special");
    const minLength = document.getElementById("length");

    // get all li items with valid className
    const liList = document.querySelectorAll(".liList");

    //javascript regular expression pattern
    const data = pswrd.value;
    const lower = new RegExp("(?=.*[a-z])");
    const upper = new RegExp("(?=.*[A-Z])");
    const number = new RegExp("(?=.*[0-9])");
    const special = new RegExp("(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])");
    const length = new RegExp("(?=.{8,})");

    //lowerCase validation

    if (lower.test(data)) {
      lowerCase.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      lowerCase.classList.remove("valid");
    }
    if (upper.test(data)) {
      upperCase.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      upperCase.classList.remove("valid");
    }
    if (number.test(data)) {
      digit.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      digit.classList.remove("valid");
    }
    if (special.test(data)) {
      specialChar.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      specialChar.classList.remove("valid");
    }
    if (length.test(data)) {
      minLength.classList.add("valid");
    } else {
      minLength.classList.remove("valid");
    }

    if (
      lower.test(data) &&
      upper.test(data) &&
      number.test(data) &&
      special.test(data) &&
      length.test(data)
    ) {
      setShowValidation(false);
    } else {
      setShowValidation(true);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Hide the entire component if there are no validations

```
 return (
      {showValidation && 
          <div className={showValidation ? "validation active" : "validation "}>
              <ul>
                <li classList="liList" id="lower">
                  At least one lowercase character
                </li>
                <li classList="liList" id="upper">
                  At least one uppercase character
                </li>
                <li classList="liList" id="number">
                  At least one number
                </li>
                <li classList="liList" id="special">
                  At least one special character
                </li>
                <li classList="liList" id="length">
                  At least 8 characters
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
         }
        )
```

update the condition like this

```
if ([lowerCase,upper,number,special,].some(i => i.classList.contains("valid") === true)) {
```

Comment: what I want is a way to check in all list items has the valid className, if all of them have it than I want to hide the validation list